# How to import only a part of json file in react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack, import

I use a json file as a config file. In a react component, I do not need all parameters. 
For example,
**myjson.json** file

```
{
  "part1": {
    "param1": 12,
    "param2": "aaa"
  },
  "part2": {
    "param1": 47,
    "param2": "bbb"
  }
}
```

In my **xxx.js** file, with the code `import myjson from './myjson.json';` , I get the whole json file in the `myjson` object.
How can I **directly** import only `part1` of the json file?
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: import { part1 } from './myjson.json'

Comment: it isn't a JavaScript module file - it's straight JSON in a text file (no export statements).

Comment: @RandyCasburn in React it does work. This answer is valid

Comment: But I use reactjs. I think webpack must do the job. Right ? (It works)